# Arabic<->English layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, arabic

Hi I'm new to android world. I'm working on an application that supports arabic and english languages.So I made my design for english language in the xml and through the code when the user wants to work with arabic language I change the gravity of my widgets to match the arabic right-to-left look.

Now if the user changes the language from english to arabic and for some reason he wanted to get back to english again.How can I restore the layout in the xml again?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be more comfortable for you to create two layouts and switch them in right order.

Comment: Thanks for replying me :).But it's gonna increase the size of my application.

Comment: Usually layouts weigh a couple of kilobytes, I don't think you should worry about it.

Comment: If I'm working with only one xml then I'll have to set the gravity or make ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT for each widget in my xml?

Comment: But I have a problem here.I have a list in xml and the row it in another xml when I try to make ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT to the row xml it throws exception

Comment: source not found exception at this line of code:-   //threads row
//lastPost
tvThread=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLastPost); 
 params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tvThread.getLayoutParams();//here
   params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
but it switches the list's widget normally

Comment: It's hard to understand what you've written here, maybe you should create a separate question?